# how to save objects with an undefined and large number of parameters?

Tags: save

I want to create a mobile app where you can create challenges. The problem is that I don't know what is the best way to save all the challenges, because :

1. You can have many challenges
2. I have a lot of parameters to save (>50) for each challenge you create
3. The number of parameters of each challenge can vary a lot, and the parameters can be different from a challenge to another...

   Thanks.